# How to hold values used to calculations in c++ template class?

Tags: c++, function, templates, member

Hello I have doubt about keeping values used to calculation in c++ template class.

The scenario is following, we have a plenty of functions which are using some nested calculations in their calculations for setting some states/values etc. Those nested calculations are repetitive for all of those functions.

The problem is in which approach is correct, in case of templates? Keeping those values as member value? Or just calling inline function which will perform calculation inplace? Lets say value of that member function/value is calculated based on template argument and its size and there are some mathematical operations like multiplication, subtraction and divivision, generally say difficult mathematics formula which we don't want to repeat.

Approach with member value:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class ApproachWithMemberValue {
public:
    void firstOperation()
    {
        member_ = (member_ / importantValueUsedMultipleTime_) + something;
    }

    void secondOperation()
    {
        member_ = (1 / (member_ / importantValueUsedMultipleTime_)) * something;
    }

    //And other plenty of functions which uses importantValueUsedMultipleTime_

private:
    T val_;
    size_t member_;
    constexpr size_t importantValueUsedMultipleTime_ = resultOfOperations;
    //Some mathematical computations based on type of val_ and its value but calculated directly in importantValueUsedMultipleTime_
};
```

Approach with member function:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class ApproachWithMemberFunction {
public:
    void firstOperation()
    {
        member_ = (member_ / getImportantValueUsedMultipleTime()) + something;
    }

    void secondOperation()
    {
        member_ = (1 / (member_ / getImportantValueUsedMultipleTime())) * something;
    }

    //And other plenty of functions which uses getImportantValueUsedMultipleTime()

private:
    T val_;
    size_t member_;

    constexpr inline size_t getImportantValueUsedMultipleTime()
    {
        //Some mathematical computations based on type of val_ and its value
        return resultOfOperation;
    }
};
```

Which approach is better in computation efficiency and code quality? Will calling function getImportantValueUsedMultipleTime() return computed value or put calculation in place where it is used?

Comment: If you want a review of your code, you can ask the question on this [code review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question you asked, it seems that, without optimizations, the version that calls the [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) function directly, without storing it in a `static constexpr` member, can generate more code. This difference would probably go away with optimizations, but if you want to be extra sure you can declare the function [`consteval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval). See the generated code for each version: https://godbolt.org/z/46xeebbcn

Now, to hopefully answer the question you meant to ask. You need to initialize a `static constexpr` member with something, in your case presumably a `constexpr` function that can be evaluated at compile-time, call it `getImporantValueUsedMultipleTimes()`. If this functions depends on the "type of `val_` and its value", then it cannot be evaluated at compile-time, since `val_` is a run-time variable.

The solution you are probably looking for is some type of [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). If you really want the computation to be done at compile-time then maybe something like this: https://godbolt.org/z/o7cqzjjbW

```
template<typename T>
consteval T computeValue(T arg) {
    return arg * 2;
};

template<typename T>
struct MemoizedValues {
    static inline const std::unordered_map<T, T> k_Values{
        {0, computeValue(0)},
        {1, computeValue(1)}};
};

template<typename T>
T getPrecomputedValue(T arg) {
    return MemoizedValues<T>::k_Values.at(arg);
};

template<typename T>
struct UsingMemoizedValues
{
    T foo() {
        return getPrecomputedValue(m_val);
    }

    T m_val;
};

int main() {
    UsingMemoizedValues<int>{}.foo();
}
```

But this requires that you know at compile-time all the possible argument values that you might get at run-time (in the example only 0 and 1 are supported), which is a tall ask. More likely you'd need a system that caches the results of a `constexpr` (note, not `consteval`) `computeValue()` at run-time, and returns that if asked a second time. If you know that there are some values that are commonly used you could initialize the cache with results for those values, as long as you use literals or `constexpr` arguments then `computeValue()` should be evaluated at compile-time.

Of course, there are open-source libraries that do this for you, for example https://github.com/jimporter/memo.